# WPF - Defining DataTemplate inside ResourceDictionary without a key

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have seen many times wpf code samples in this form:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SomeType}">
        <!-- Elements defining the DataTemplate-->
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

I understand the usage, but I cant understand why is this syntax is ok: since ResourceDictionary implements IDictionary, therefore every element that we add to Resource property must specify a key. Now I know that using the DictionaryKeyPropertyAttribute, a class can provide an implicit key value - but in case of DataTemplate class, the provided property is "DataTemplateKey". I know it sounds a bit petty, but the motivation for this question is to know how to use other classes even if I didnt have the privilege to see usage samples before (maybe some 3rd party...). anyone?

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned in your question, entries without an `x:Key` attribute use [DataTemplateKey(SomeType)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557261.aspx) as the key. You can only specify one such instance for a particular `SomeType` in the resources. DataTemplateKey is derived from [TemplateKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatekey.aspx) which itself is derived from [ResourceKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcekey.aspx). Of course such DataTemplate resource definitions can appear for many types, staying unique, because the DataTemplateKey of each respective type will be unique.

For example, consider the following Resources definition:

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <!-- Generic Button data template -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Button}">
      <!-- Elements defining the DataTemplate-->
    </DataTemplate>
    <!-- Generic TextBlock data template -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
      <!-- Elements defining the DataTemplate-->
    </DataTemplate>
    <!-- Specific Button data template -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SpecialButton" DataType="{x:Type Button}">
      <!-- Elements defining the DataTemplate-->
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
```

This results in three entries in the resource dictionary. The orange arrows in the image, below, point to the `DataTemplateKey` based entries for the `Button` and `TextBlock` types, while the red arrow points to the specific (keyed) entry for the `SpecialButton` keyed resource:

[image]

Comment: Michael: Thank you for your detailed answer, though I still have a  problem - I didnt understand how the DataType property (of object type) is related to DataTemplateKey type that you mentioned. I think my confusion is based on the fact that there are both "DataTemplateKey" type AND "DataTemplateKey" property NAME of type object... As I understand from the documentation, the DictionaryKeyPropertyAttribute that wraps the DataTemplate class is related to the "DataTemplateKey" property, which is of object type. Could you please clarify that point? thanks again.